# NSTemporaryDirectory files are write protected from other processes

Tags: macos, filesystems

I want to open some data (held in an NSData) in another process. So I do something like this (in swift):

```
let tempURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents([NSTemporaryDirectory(), NSUUID().UUIDString + ext])
data.writeToURL(tempURL, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic)
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(tempURL)
```

If the data is an image, the ext might be 'jpg'.

I can see the file created. Preview opens the image fine. Problem is that Preview is unable to save changes to the file. According to **ls -l** and **Get Info**, the file is definitely writable by me. Checking **lsof** on the file immediately after writing and before Preview starts, its not held open by any other processes.

Running Preview by hand on that file also results in "cannot save changes".

The temporary folder (returned by NSTemporaryDirectory() ) is:

```
/var/folders/zt/<random string of alphanum>/T
```

Since I was able to write the file, I'm forced to guess that the new OSX security enhancements for temporary files means that only the creator process can write to those files. If I move the file out to my desktop, I can open it, and if I use a hard coded "/tmp" for the temporary folder, everything works.

According to **man 7 tier**, /var/folders is:

> per-user temporary files and caches

Nothing I can find mentions cross-process security in temporary folders. 
Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Cheers.
Paul

Comment: Are you using app sandbox?

Comment: Currently set to "off" under Target | Capabilities (as are all options in there).